# How to get python time to update

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to create a program that allows you to ask the current time. The problem is that the program only prints the time of its execution, not the actual current time.

My code:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

user_input = input("")

if user_input == "what time is it":
    print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))
```

If I started the program at 6:25, no matter what time it is, the program returns 6:25.

Comment: move the line `now = datetime.datetime.now()` underneath the `if user_input == "what time is it":` line (and indent it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to

```py
import datetime

user_input = input("")

if user_input == "what time is it":
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))
```

the `now` variable is holding the timestamp of when you called the `now` function

Answer (score 1):

The program is hitting the `now = datetime.datetime.now()` command when you run, not when you input. To solve this problem, just put the code inside the if statement. It will then time stamp the moment you enter your input.